# Error in a simple react-redux connect function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am receiving the following error when trying to use the "connect" function of react-redux:

```
"TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default.a.memo is not a function"
```

Also there are the following details:

```
wrapWithConnect
C:/.../node_modules/react-redux/es/components/connectAdvanced.js:325
  322 | } // If we're in "pure" mode, ensure our wrapper component only re-renders when incoming props have changed.
  323 | 
  324 | 
> 325 | var Connect = pure ? React.memo(ConnectFunction) : ConnectFunction;
  326 | Connect.WrappedComponent = WrappedComponent;
  327 | Connect.displayName = displayName;
  328 |
```

I didn't find any reference to this error in correlation to my problem yet...

This is the code I used with "connect" at the end of the "Chat.js" class:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


  ...


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addMessage: () => dispatch(addMessage)
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Chat);
```

This code is used in a class called "Chat.js". When using "export default Chat" without the redux "connect" everything is ok.

I used the provider tag as a wrapper to the chat component in the "App.js":

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
const App = class extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { title } = this.context;
    return (
      <div className="center-screen">
        {title}
        <Provider store={configureStore()}>
          <Chatroom />
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Action:

```
export function addMessage(text) {
  return { type: 'addMessage', text };
}
```

Reducer:

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'addMessage':
      return {
        text: action.text
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: React.memo was renamed in [React v16.6.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/v16.6.0/packages/react/src). If you're using an older version of React library, you need to find a version of react-redux that supports that version

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule I have updated react version to the latest, now I am getting:"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `App`."

Comment: What is the instance of `title`? Check that `title` isn't a plain Object where you expect that it's a String. Also check in `Chatroom` that no plain Object attempts to be rendered there.

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule I am getting the same error even without the title though

Answer (score 0):

share the webpack file too.so that i can check if there is any problem in webpack setup

Comment: Prefer comments when asking for more info.

Comment: I am not sure if I have one, I am using create react app